# couchbase: restore from backup zip

Tags: couchbase

I have the backup of the couchbase taken using /opt/couchbase/bin/cbbackup from a dev box as backup_dev.zip
Now, I wanted to restore the backup_dev.zip to the couchbase running locally on my machine.
So, I installed Couchbase server which is the latest version which said cbrestore is deprecated. I ran the below command, reference from https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-restore.html link.

```
./cbbackupmgr restore -a backups_dev.zip -r <folder inside backups_dev.zip> -c http://localhost:8091 -u <username> -p <password>
```

This throws error saying backup_dev.zip is a file, not a directory.

Could you suggest please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you took your backup using cbbackup, then you have to use cbrestore to restore.  (cbbackupmgr is used for both backup and restore, and to use cbbackupmgr restore command, you must have taken the backup using cbbackupmgr backup.)

https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/cli/cbtools/cbrestore.html

Can see examples of using cbrestore command in the documentation.  You'll need to unzip the backups_dev.zip.